# How can I move right quick filter bar in the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

[image]

Hi, I'm using SherlockActivity and I need to move the quick filter bar to the right (sorry if I was not the real name)

How I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to attach EditText in your ActionBar as your filter input field.

1. Define your menu:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@+id/search"
     android:icon="@android:drawable/search"
     android:actionLayout="@layout/search"
     android:showAsAction="never"
     android:title="@string/about">
   </item>
   </menu>
   ```
2. In onCreateOptionsMenu() method add action layout to your item:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

       EditText add= (EditText)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView()
                                                      .findViewById(R.id.title);

       add.setOnEditorActionListener(this);           

      return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
   }
   ```
3. Define your action layout search.xml:

   ```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Word:"
               android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>

       <EditText
               android:id="@+id/title"
               android:layout_width="100sp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
               android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
               android:imeActionId="1337"
               android:imeOptions="actionDone"
               android:inputType="text"/>    
       </LinearLayout>
   ```
4. Your activity/fragment should implement TextView.OnEditorActionListener or you can add this as anonymous class in onCreateOptionsMenu:

   ```
     @Override
     public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        v.getText(); //your input CharSequence to be handled by FilterQueryProvider for example              
     }
   ```

   Is this a solution for you ?